# Is there a way to have Windows 10 honor pywinauto.mouse.move after tapping on touchscreen?

Tags: python, ui-automation, windows-10-universal, touchscreen

I'm writing a python 3/kivy app that sends keycommands to another application on Windows 10 using pywinauto.

The kivy interface runs on a secondary touchscreen monitor. When touching a button on the kivy GUI the mouse cursor is moved to the touched position - to me this is normal behavior and expected. However, what is not expected is when I use pywinauto.mouse.move to move the cursor back in a centered position of the main display and subsequently use the attached hardware mouse, the cursor is back at the prior position on the touchscreen.

In other words, my python script does indeed seem to move the cursor to the main display, as that is visually what happens, but somehow another part of Windows 10 is not updated with the pywinauto.mouse.move command. This only happens when the touchscreen is what's used. If I move the mouse-pointer with the hardware mouse, and then reset the pointer with pywinauto.mouse.move, that move is then honored by Windows 10.

I'm at a loss of where to go look for information on this problem, probably because I'm not familiar with the right terms to do a proper search, which I apologize for.